# ProgressBar inside Toolbar not shown in android

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar, android-toolbar

I have the following xml

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar">

            <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbarprogress"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:shadowColor="@color/red"
                    android:rotation="@integer/google_play_services_version"
                    android:layout_height="25dp" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

and in my activity I had those two methods

```
protected fun showProgress() {

        toolbarprogress?.let {
            it.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    protected fun hideProgress() {

        toolbarprogress?.let {
            it.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
```

the problem that when I call showProgress method it does not shown in my toolbar , can anyone advice what is missing here ?

Comment: Is `toolbarprogress == null`?

Comment: No it is not equal null

Answer (score 0):

I've used the same code and its working fine with mine.
Make sure you use `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` if your toolbar is not visible.